# List and create in same view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following model classes

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> LProducts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{    
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
}
```

then I have following view for both List and Create

```
@model albaraka.Models.ProductViewModel    

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Detail
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var obj in Model.LProducts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obj.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obj.detail)
            </td>       
        </tr>   
    }

</table>

<div>
    @using ())
    {
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.id)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Products.id)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Products.id)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Products.detail)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Products.detail)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Products.detail)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@section Scripts 
{}
```

this is controller method for list

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Product_List()
{
    ProductViewModel viewModelList = new ProductViewModel();

    viewModelList.LProducts = from products in db.Product
                  where products.details == "Pending"
                  select products;

    return View(viewModelList.LProducts.ToList());
}
```

but here I'm getting following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[projectname.Models.Product]', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'projectname.Models.ProductViewModel'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory, your view accepts `@model albaraka.Models.ProductViewModel` not `@model IList<albaraka.Models.ProductViewModel>`. In your view you are using `@model albaraka.Models.ProductViewModel` which indicates that the model expected by the View is of type `ProductViewModel`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Product_List()
{
    ProductViewModel viewModelList = new ProductViewModel();

    viewModelList.LProducts = (from products in db.AB_Product
                  where products.details == "Pending"
                  select products).ToList();

    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

Comment: You've missed actual linq query execution with `ToList()` before passing model to thу view.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what the issue is. You're supplying a list of Product objects to the view instead of the ProductModelView that it's expecting. Change your controller code to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Product_List()
{
    ProductViewModel viewModelList = new ProductViewModel();

    viewModelList.LProducts = (from products in db.Product
                  where products.details == "Pending"
                  select products).ToList();

    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, exception text is self-explanatory - you're passing incorrect type to the view.

It should be

```
public ViewResult Product_List()
{
    ProductViewModel viewModelList = new ProductViewModel();

    viewModelList.LProducts = (from products in db.Product
                  where products.details == "Pending"
                  select products).ToList();

    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason of the error is type mismatch of what you pass as argument (List) and what is expected by view (instance of `ProductViewModel` class).

In your controller, instead of the line:

```
return View(viewModelList.LProducts.ToList());
```

Try the following:

```
return View(
   new ProductViewModel {LProducts = viewModelList.LProducts.ToList()}
);
```